# Typescript protected object contains public members

Tags: typescript, protected

Why there is no compiler error, when writing `dataField` of protected object within class `Something` that is not derived of class parent?

I expected that `this.obj.data` and all properties are read-only. But compiler only throws error for `this.obj.data = new Data()`, because it's protected property. It doesn't throw error, if writing to properties inside this object (`this.obj.data.dataField = "something"`), because they are public again.

In which use case does it make sense, where protected object contains public properties?

```
export class Data {
  public dataField: string = "empty";
}
export abstract class Parent {
  protected _dd: Data = new Data();
    
  public get data(): Data {
    return this._dd;
  }
}

export class Child extends Parent {
 constructor() {        
    super();
    this._dd.dataField = "hello";
  }
}

export class Something {
  obj: Child;  
  constructor() {       
    this.obj = new Child();
    this.obj.data.dataField = "hello world";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a confusion: the field `Parent._dd` (and, subsequently, `Child._dd`) is protected, but because of the **public** getter, you can access it by using `.data` everywhere you have an instance of `Parent` (in this case, `Child`).

> I expected that this.obj.data and all properties are read-only. But compiler only throws error for this.obj.data = new Data(), because it's protected property.

`this.obj.data` is read-only¹: you can't replace `data` (actually, `_dd`) with another object (not from inside `Something` class) because you don't have a public setter. But, since their properties are public (or have public setters), they aren't read-only.

> In which use case does it make sense, where protected object contains public properties?

If you didn't have that public getter, you could have methods in `Child`/`Parent` classes that manipulated specific fields of `Data` class. This way, you could control which fields could be changed. For instance:

```js
export class Data {
  public dataField: string = "empty";
  public anotherField: string = "maybe empty";
}
export abstract class Parent {
  protected _dd: Data = new Data();

  public get dataField(): string {
    return this._dd.dataField;
  }

  public get anotherField(): string {
    return this._dd.anotherField;
  }
    
  public set anotherField(anotherField: string): void {
    this._dd.anotherField = anotherField;
  }
}

export class Child extends Parent {
 constructor() {        
    super();
    this._dd.dataField = "hello";
  }
}

export class Something {
  obj: Child;  
  constructor() {       
    this.obj = new Child();

    // ERROR because of lack of dataField setter - so, dataField is 'read-only',
    // as in, only Child/Parent and Data itself can manipulate it
    this.obj.dataField = "hello world"; 

    // OK because it's using anotherField setter, which access underlying _dd
    this.obj.anotherField = "hello world"; 

    // NOTICE that accessing this.obj._dd would error, so you can manipulate
    // fields of Data only using getter/setter specified in the containing class,
    // you have no way to manipulate Data itself from Something.
  }
}
```

*Notice: I've implemented them as getter/setter, but I'm not sure this is good practice, to have getter/setters changing fields from nested objects. It's more of educational.*

But the point is: the use of having public fields in protected object is that if you don't expose the protected object (no public getter or public method returning it), you can control it's access.

---

<sub>¹ Notice: from my understanding, OP is using "read-only" as in "can't be changed from `Something`'s pov". So, every time I mention read-only, it's in that same context. [Not to be confused with `readonly` keyword](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-readonly).</sub>